# Use client-side query to generate CSV file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, breeze

I have a functional app using breeze. Now I need to be able to export CSV files with the data. What would be nice to be able to do is to use the breeze client-side query system to get the data. Eg.: Today I already have a method in my controller:

```
public IQueryable<Movie> Movies()
{        
    return _context.Context.Movies;
}
```

and on client side I can create filters, etc. Is it possible to do something so I can do something like

```
public string ExportMovies()
{        
    var movies = _context.Context.Movies;
    //movies holds my filtered list
    var csvFile = movies.ToCSV("path")
    //return the path to the user download
    return path;
}
```

My biggest problem is that I want to re-utilize breeze client-side query capabilities instead of creating one of my one. Since breeze expetc to get Entity data I do not see how or if this is doable... is it possible?

Comment: Are you trying to make a CSV file with a matrix of data or just simply arrays into a CSV?

Comment: I want to return the (in the case of the example) movie table (or a projection, called from the client-side) in CSV format.